# If $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, then $\hat{f}(\omega)‎\to0$ as $‎\omega‎ \to+‎\infty‎$?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

The Fourier transform of $f$ is as follows:
$$\hat{f}(\omega)=\frac{1}{‎‎‎\sqrt{2‎\pi‎}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-i\omega t} f(t) \, dt.$$
I need to know that if $f \in L^1(R)$, then can we conclude that  $\hat{f}$ is bounded and continuous and $\hat{f}(\omega)‎\to 0$ as $‎\omega‎ \to+‎\infty‎$?
It would be appreciated if someone could help me.

Comment: Do you know, for instance, that if $f\in L^1(\mathbb R)$ and you define $f_t(x)=f(x-t)$ that $\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\|f_t-f\|_1 = 0$? Or that this statement is true in the case of $f\in L^1(S_1)$ where $S_1$ is the circle? Either of these facts are useful here.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. For $0 < R < \infty$ and $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, the function
$$
             \hat{f_R}(\omega)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-R}^{R}f(t)e^{-ist}dt
$$
is infinitely differentiable with
$$
           \hat{f_{R}}^{(n)}(s)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-R}^{R}f(t)(-it)^{n}e^{-ist}dt.
$$
Furthermore, one has the uniform convergence to $0$ of the function:
$$
         |\hat{f_{R}}(\omega)-\hat{f}(\omega)| \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{|t| \ge R}|f(t)|dt \rightarrow 0,\mbox{ as $R\rightarrow\infty$}.
$$
The uniform limit of continuous functions is continuous. So $\hat{f}$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. The Riemann-Lebesgue lemma gives
$$
       \lim_{s\rightarrow\infty}\hat{f}(s)=   \lim_{s\rightarrow\pm\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-ist}dt =0.
$$

Answer (score 3):

Note that the $\mathcal{C}^\infty_c$ functions are dense in $\mathcal{L}^1$.  This theorem is true for a smooth function; you can see this by integrating by parts. Now invoke the density to see it holds for any $f\in\mathcal{L}^1$.

Comment: (it is true for any $L^1$ smooth function ^^ in particular when it has compact support)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is usaully called the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma. See for instance the section "The Fourier transform on $L^1$" in Hunter's [notes](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/book/ch11.pdf):

[image]